# When a $\mathbb{P}$ - generic filter is $\kappa$ - complete?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

By definition a $\mathbb{P}$ - generic filter $G$ over a ground model $M$ is $\aleph_0$ - complete because for any finite set of conditions in $G$ there is a condition $p\in G$ such that $p$ is stronger than them all. This is similar to being closed under intersection of finitely many members for a usual filter on a set.

**Q)** What are examples of sufficient conditions on forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ and possibly ground model $M$, such that any $\mathbb{P}$ - generic filter $G$ over $M$ is $\kappa$ - complete in the sense that "*for any set of conditions of size $<\kappa$ in $G$ there is a condition $p\in G$ ( not $p\in \mathbb{P}$) such that $p$ is stronger than them all.*"

Comment: Note that every generic $G$ is $M$-complete, meaning that it has lower bounds for sets in $M$ (this is easy to see by passing to the Boolean completion). So if $\mathbb{P}$ doesn't add sets of size $<\kappa$, any generic will be $\kappa$-complete in your sense.

Comment: @MihaHabič So do you mean that generic filters on $\kappa$ - closed and $\kappa$ - distributive forcing notions are $\kappa$ - complete?

Comment: That's right.$\ $